# UpdatePanel within Loop not updating textbox

Tags: vb.net

Hi I am trying to use the UpdatePanel within a For Each Loop. Right now it waits until the entire process is complete and then displays all the text at once. AddRecords actually loops three times (three different recordsets). I would like it to update every time it adds to the textbox. I have tried timers and button clicks, but once I click "Start Records" button - it does not allow me to press anything else until it has completed.

.aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <fieldset>
             <legend>UpdatePanel</legend>
                <asp:TextBox ID="ReportTextBox" runat="server" Height="233px" Width="430px"></asp:TextBox><br />
           </fieldset>
      </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code Behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Me.ReportTextBox)
End Sub

Protected Sub AddRecords(ByVal dt As DataTable)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Me.ReportTextBox.Text = row.EquipNumber + vbNewLine
        UpdatePanel1.Update()
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It isn't possible because the server waits for the entire loop to finish processing and then sends the data back to the webpage, So update can never really update until the data is actually there.